# Linking in response to an email

Tags: html, email

I use Thunderbird to comunicate with my clients. I created a footer with my data. Unfortunately, the mail converted my email address and website link to "links" and blue text. I decided to use CSS with

```html
 a.link {
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;

    }
```

And works great ! But when the customer responds to my message and sends it to me, I receive a converted email address and a link to the page in blue text or link. The problem is that such messages often go to spam. Another issue is I have to remove some of the footer from the answer, otherwise the customer will receive a "linked" footer as a response. How can I make the customer not convert part of the footer into links when replying to my message? Below I paste a picture. The first is the message that the customer receives, while the second photo shows the message with my footer to which the customer responded.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIq6G.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVVDf.png)

And here is my HTML code

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Enail Footer</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>

<!-- #######  Convert blue text and "www" & "@" to normal text #########-->

<style>
    a.link {
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;

    }

</style>

<body>

    <table style="width: 400px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height:normal;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td width="400" style="width:400px" colspan="2"> <span style="font-size:10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000;">Best regards</span> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="400" style="width:400px; padding-top:5px" colspan="2"> <span style="font-size:18pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000; padding-bottom:5px;">My name</span> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="400" style="width:400px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right:15px; border-right:2px solid #d7bda6" width="162" valign="top"><span><img width="192" border="0" alt="Logo" style="border:0;max-width:830px; padding-top:15px;" src="http://beiga.pl/wp-content/themes/beiga/img/logo.png"></span> </td>

                   <td style="padding-left:15px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                        <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="http://designstrony.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/telefon-01-1.png" alt="Telefon" width="25" height="25" />
                            <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;">000 000 000<br></span>
                        <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="http://designstrony.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/email-01-1.png" alt="Email" width="25" height="25" />
                            <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;">beiga<a class="link">@</a>website.com<br></span>
                        <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="http://designstrony.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/witryna-01-1.png" alt="Witryna" width="25" height="25" /> 
                            <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;"><a class="link">www.website.com</a><br></span>
                    <span>
                        <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="http://designstrony.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/facebook-01.png" alt="Facebook" width="25" height="25" />
                            <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;">facebook.com/<br></span></span> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The email client adds color to links, ie a anchors. Its because you add <a> tag that you have a color. Try other tags, like user<i>@</i>domain and www<i>.</i>domain<i>.</i>extension.

Comment: @iguypouf works very well ! Thanks for help :) +rep for you.